# Инициализация объекта импортированного класса при изменении свойства VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, классы, видео

Есть компонент плеер, в который я импортирую класс `Player` .
В компоненте `Player` есть свойство `videoInfo`, которое возвращает ссылку на поток для плеера.
Каждый раз когда меняется ссылка, вызываем метод из импортируемого класса. В этом методе инициализируется плеер. В классе есть функция `changeUrl` которая смотрит в хранилище `vuex` и берет оттуда ссылку на поток, далее ссылка загружается в плеер.
Проблема заключается в том, что при многократной смене ссылок, инициализируется новые плееры и накладываются друг она друга.

[image: картинка]

Как я понимаю, я как-то не правильно инициализирую объект.
Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как можно это исправить.

**Player.vue**

```
import Player from '../common/Player';

export default {
    name: "Player",
    props: {
      'videoInfo': Object
    },
    watch: {
      videoInfo(newVideoUrl) { //следим, поменялся ли поток
        var a = new Player();
        a.changeUrl(newVideoUrl);
      },
    },
  })
```

**Player .js**

```
import store from "../nstore/index"; //vuex

export default class Player {

    constructor() {
        this.video = document.getElementById('video');
        this.videoContainer = document.getElementById('videoContainer');
        this.player = new shaka.Player(this.video);
        this.ui = new shaka.ui.Overlay(this.player, this.videoContainer, this.video);
        this.controls = this.ui.getControls();
        this.changeUrl();

        this.controls.addEventListener('caststatuschanged', (e) => this.onCastStatusChanged(e));
    }

    async changeUrl() {
        var videoUrl = store.state.tvplayer.url;
        try {
            await this.player.load(videoUrl);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    onCastStatusChanged(event) {
        alert(event);
        this.newCastStatus = event['newStatus'];
        console.log('The new cast status is: ' + this.newCastStatus);
    }

    onPlayerErrorEvent(errorEvent) {
        this.onPlayerError(event.detail);
    }

    onPlayerError(error) {
        console.error('Error code', error.code, 'object', error);
    }

    onUIErrorEvent(errorEvent) {
        this.onPlayerError(event.detail);
    }

    initFailed() {
        console.error('Unable to load the UI library!');
    }


}
```

Comment: Почему бы в `data` не задать свойство `player: null` и в хуке `mounted`/`created` не выполнять единую инициализацию: `this.player = new Player();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поместить объект параметров в стор стейт:

```
state: {
  // ... 
  playerParams: { url: '' }
}, 
mutations: {
  // ... 
  PLAYER_PARAMS(state, paramsObj) {
    state.playerParams = { ...state.playerParams, ...paramsObj }; 
  }
}
```

И в компоненте подписаться на его мутацию:

```
import Player from '../common/Player';

export default {
  name: 'Player',
  data: () => ({
    plr
  }), 
  mounted() {
    this.plr = new Player(); 
    this.plr.changeUrl(this.$store.state.playerParams.url); 
    this.$store.subscribe((mutation, { playerParams }) => {
      if (mutation.type === 'PLAYER_PARAMS')
        this.plr.changeUrl(playerParams.url); 
    }); 
  }
});
```

, предварительно изменив метод `changeUrl` следующим образом:

```
async changeUrl(videoUrl) {
  try {
    await this.player.load(videoUrl);
  } catch (error) { console.error(error); }
}
```

Изменение `url` можно будет выполнять в любом родительском компоненте:

```
this.$store.commit('PLAYER_PARAMS', {
  url: 'https://example.com/sample.mp4'
});
```

При новых значениях из синхронного кода, экшн не обязателен.

**p.s.:** Стор лучше подключать [правильно](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/state.html), а не так как вопросе.
**p.p.s.:** Пишу с мобилы, поэтому возможны очепятки и ашыпки.